# travis-ci multiple build stages for each matrix element

Tags: travis-ci

I am trying to run two stages, `test_it` and `package_it`, for each element of a build matrix. If all jobs in the `test_it` stage pass, then I want to do all the `package_it` jobs.

I have a `.travis.yml` file that does what I want, but verbosely with repetitions. What is the best way to get the same effect?

```
sudo: false

language: cpp

cache:
  ccache: true

jobs:
  include:
    - stage: test_it
      os: linux
      dist: trusty
      compiler: gcc
      addons:
        apt:
          packages:
            - bash-completion
            - curl
      script: echo "test_it on $TRAVIS_OS_NAME"
    - stage: test_it
      os: osx
      compiler: clang
      script: echo "test_it on $TRAVIS_OS_NAME"
    - stage: package_it
      os: linux
      dist: trusty
      compiler: gcc
      addons:
        apt:
          packages:
            - bash-completion
            - curl
      script: echo "package_it on $TRAVIS_OS_NAME"
    - stage: package_it
      os: osx
      compiler: clang
      script: echo "package_it on $TRAVIS_OS_NAME"
```